# jquery ajax Reloading part of a page returning undefined

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to reload a section of a page:

```
function LoadAssets() {
  console.log($('#AssetResults').html());
  $.ajax({
    url : 'Assets_Home.cfm',
    type : 'POST',
    success : function(data) {
      console.log($(data).find('#AssetResults').html());
      $("#AssetResults").html($(data).find('#AssetResults').html());
    }
  });
}
```

Where Assets_Home.cfm is the current page. Data returns the page correctly, $(data) looks like this in the console:

```
w.fn.init(38) [text, comment, text, script, text, meta, text, link, text, script, text, script, text, script, text, script, text, link, text, link, text, link, text, link, text, title, text, style, text, div#NavigationBar, text, comment, text, div, text, div#AssetResults, text, script]
```

And `$(data).find('#AssetResults').html()` is undefined.

Am I not selecting it right?

Comment: you mean `console.log` is working, and the same syntax is giving error in next line?

Comment: try `$("#AssetResults").replaceWith($(data).find('#AssetResults').html());`

Comment: Try saving the data in a variable and use that variable afterwards.

Comment: @kiddorails No, console.log isn't getting an error, it's just saying that $(data).find('#AssetResults').html() is undefined, but it's definitely in the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find()` searches the contents of elements, but it doesn't find the top-level elements themselves. So you need to wrap the returned value in another element.

```
var div = $("<div>", { html: data });
var assetResults = div.find("#assetResults").html();
```

You could also use the `.load()` method, which allows you to put a selector in the URL.

```
$("#AssetResults").load('Assets_Home.cfm #AssetResults');
```

Comment: Okay .load works and is simpler. Thanks for that. And yeah, my original problem was I didn't realize there wasn't any parent tag (I thought <body> was being supplied by a header and footer, it isn't )

Comment: If there were, the console log output would look like `[body]`.